# javascript assign a function to a variable without running it

Tags: javascript

I have defined a global variable ff and then call f1 to assign function f3 to it.
When I call f2, f3 will running.

```
var ff;
function f1() { ff=f3; }
function f2() { ff(); }
function f3() { alert("hello"); }
```

but if f3 take a parameter as following

```
function f3(txt) { alert(txt); }
```

and I call f1 to assign ff as following

```
function f1() { ff=f3("hello"); }
```

f3 will run at the same time.

I don't want f3 running when I assign it to ff and I need pass a argument.
How can I achieve this?
A variable with () after it as if will make it a function and make it run.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
ff = f3.bind(null, "hello")
```

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `ff` the value of the `f3` call, in your second example, which is why it calls your function. You should make the assignment `ff=f3`, as you did initially. Then you can call ff with a parameter: `ff("hello")`

Comment: I may assign f4 which takes different numbers of parameters to ff in f1 according to different condition. So I can not call ff with a parameter in f2.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
var ff;
function f1() { ff=f3; }
function f2() { ff('hello'); }
function f3(text) { alert(text); }
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem